# Код по зажиганию одного рандомного светодиода из семи

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, arduino, arduino-uno

Есть 7 светодиодов и одна кнопка. Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки рандомно загорался один светодиод, при следующем нажатии, гас этот светодиод и так же рандомно загорался другой светодиод.

Накидал вот такой код. Код рабочий. Понимаю, что код плохой, но вырасти без код ревью иначе нельзя. Если можно его как то оптимизировать  или я, что то не так сделал, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#define bt 12
int buttonstate;
int butflag;
uint32_t tmr;
int x; // ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ХРАНЯЩЕЕ РАНДОМНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
int led[] = {4,5,6,7,8,9};

void setup() {
    randomSeed(analogRead(0)); 
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT); //
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //  
    pinMode(bt, INPUT_PULLUP); //ИНИЦИАЛИЗИРУЕМ ПИНЫ
}


void loop() {
   buttonstate = digitalRead(bt);
   if(buttonstate == HIGH  && butflag == 0  && millis() - tmr > 100)
   {
    butflag = 1;
    tmr = millis();
    x = led[random(0,6)];
    if(butflag == 1)
     {
      digitalWrite(x, HIGH);
     }
   }
  
  
 if(buttonstate == LOW && butflag == 1 && millis() - tmr > 100)
   {
   tmr = millis();
   butflag = 0;
   if(butflag == 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(x, LOW); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Язык то какой? Добавьте тэг

Comment: @CrazyElf *"The Arduino Programming Language is basically a framework built on top of C++"*

Comment: 1. В функции setup можно использовать цикл по всем значениям `led[]`  для установки OUTPUT. 2. Добавьте глобальную переменную для хранения предыдущего состояния кнопки. Если состояние изменилось с LOW на HIGH, гасите все леды и зажигайте один из них.

Comment: Когда это заработает, добавьте логику для debouncing. А может быть, debouncing и не нужен. Всегда сначала пробуют без, добавляют только в случае необходимости.

Comment: @AlexF благодарю за подсказку